# Adding a link to windows directory under tags in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework, testcase

I'm currently working on the Robot Framework for some automated test cases, which included a couple of html screenshots I wrote on python.

[image]

I tried putting `C:\Users\teo_y\Desktop\test` directly under the tags for the test case, it still show the similar output instead of the link to my windows directory.

Comment: Can you add your Robot Framework Script as well, as currently this can not be derived from the screenshot.

Comment: Hi Kootstra, thank you for your prompt response.
here's the ss of the simple test script.
http://imgur.com/a/9s0DN

 I'm trying to achieve a hyperlink of my windows directory from the overall report under the tagging. Do you think its possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the Tags, use the Documentation field. Use the [Set Suite Documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Documentation) keyword if you want it dynamic.

Comment: Hey Helio
Thank you for your prompt response. I've tried the Set Suit Documentation, it do show the directory, but i'm unable to have a hyperlink to my windows directory. Any idea how should i correct it?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for responding and helping out, I've found the solution to my problem.
As per Helio suggestion, i simply added a different line like the metadata [C:\Users\teo_y\Desktop\test|C:\Users\teo_y\Desktop\test] onto the documentation, and it turned out working the same outcome.

Thank you once again!

Cheers
Kia

https://i66.tinypic.com/kb97b8.png
https://i66.tinypic.com/102ntp1.png